# How do I use a loop to iterate through multiple datasets to get one output per dataset in R?

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have 60 data sets I created from one massive original one. They are split by Year, and I named them all using their year number - like Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4, etc to Year60. Each data set has a column "Car" and "Weeks". I am trying to loop through every dataset to sort by the largest Number of Cars value, take the row that value is in, and get the value for "Weeks" for that row (basically the week in which the most cars were sold per year, for each of the 60 years). 
My code is:

```
    Year1$Car <- as.integer(Year1$Car)
    df.1 <- aggregate(Car ~ Week, Year1, max)
    df.a <- merge(df.1, Year1)
    print(paste("Year 1 Most Cars Sold in Week", print(df.a$Week))
```

I am trying to find a way to run through this quicker than just manually typing for each dataset Year1, Year2, etc all the way to Year60.

I tried:

```
    for (i in 1:60){
    Year"i"$Car <- as.integer(Year"i"$Car)
    df.1 <- aggregate(Car ~ Week, Year"i", max)
    df.a <- merge(df.1, Year"i")
    print(paste("Year "i" Most Cars Sold in Week", print(df.a$Week))
    }
```

that didn't work :/ Would really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the list intact, you can use `sapply` to go through each dataframe and extract the `Week` number of row with maximum `Car` value.

```
sapply(mget(paste0('Year', 1:60)), function(x) x$Week[which.max(x$Car)])
```

---

Or with `dplyr` you can combine all the datasets into one `group_by` each `Year` and select the row with maximum value of `Car`.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(mget(paste0('Year', 1:60)), .id = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(which.max(Car))
```